# Angular Karma Mock Error response

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Test always fail because login.subscribe error don't have error.status
error.status -> 'undefined'
**Test:**

```
it('form submit fail', () => {
    expect(element.querySelector('#login-email')).toBeDefined();
    expect(element.querySelector('#login-password')).toBeDefined();
    updateForm('test@gmail.com', '123456');
    component.login(component.loginForm);
    httpMock
      .expectOne(`${environment.apiProtocol}://${environment.apiHost}/auth`)
      .error( new ErrorEvent( 'SOME_ERROR', {error: 400}), {status: 400, statusText: ''});
    httpMock.verify();
    expect(component.hasError).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.error).toEqual('unregisteredPair');
  });
```

**component.login:**

```
login(form: FormGroup): void {
    if (this.lockForm) {
      return;
    }
    if (!form.valid) {
      Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(key => {
        form.get(key).markAsTouched();
      });
      this.lockForm = false;
      return;
    }
    this.lockForm = true;
    this.hasError = false;
    this.error = '';
    this.loading = true;
    this.service.login(form.value.email, form.value.password).subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigate([this.service.redirectUrl || '/dashboard']);
      this.loading = false;
    }, (error: any) => {
      this.hasError = true;
      this.lockForm = false;
      this.error = error.status === 400 ? 'unregisteredPair' : error.error.localizationKey;
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }
```

at the end of this test got error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'localizationKey' of undefined

this happen then status != 400

Answer (score 2):

Solved this problem by using **spyOn**

**spyOn** works similar to the **httpMock** (but for calling some functions), here's an example:

```
it('form submit fail', () => {
    email.value = 'test@test.test';
    email.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    password.value = '123456';
    password.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    spyOn(service, 'login').and
      .returnValue(
        Observable.throw(
          new HttpErrorResponse({
            error: {
              message: 'Here some message...',
              localizedKey: 'someKey'
            }, 
            status: 500
          })
        )
      );
    button.click();
    expect(component.hasError).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.lockForm).toBeFalsy();
    expect(component.error).toEqual('someKey');
  });
```

In this example **spyOn** emulate response from **AuthService.login()** (when in call) and return expected response for unit testing

For success response use **Observable.of()** and **new HttpResponse()**

Comment: For rxjs 6+ use `throwError(...)` for error and `of(...)` for success. You must import them like: `import { of, throwError } from 'rxjs';`

Answer (score 0):

Manually call the `fixture.detectChanges()`

```
it('form submit fail', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(element.querySelector('#login-email')).toBeDefined();
    expect(element.querySelector('#login-password')).toBeDefined();
    updateForm('test@gmail.com', '123456');
    component.login(component.loginForm);
    httpMock
      .expectOne(`${environment.apiProtocol}://${environment.apiHost}/auth`)
      .error( new ErrorEvent( 'SOME_ERROR', {error: 400}), {status: 400, statusText: ''});
    httpMock.verify();
    expect(component.hasError).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.error).toEqual('unregisteredPair');
  });
```

Comment: is your service call is fired?